# Save a certain segment of a string

Tags: ruby, string, split

I want to split a string and save the the segment that occurs after another segment. For example

```
http://www.youtube.com/channel/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

How do I save the segment that appears after `http://www.youtube.com/channel/`, save the xxxxxx part?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Ruby has a string splitter built in.

Comment: This is actually a very good question, that isn't nearly as straightforward as some people think. It isn't a job for a string splitter. The sample given is simple but most URLs aren't that easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't just a string, it's a URL. URLs have special considerations, so there are classes written just to work with them.

Consider what a URL is: It's a reference to a remote "resource", which is usually some sort of file. So, we can use some file name manipulation on it:

```
File.basename('http://www.youtube.com/channel/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
# => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

File's [`basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-basename) method isn't very smart since it's only looking for a directory delimiter like '/'. We could use [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-split) to accomplish the same thing:

```
'http://www.youtube.com/channel/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.split('/').last
# => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

But, some URLs have query or search information, along with fragments which make both `basename` and `split` fall apart:

```
File.basename('http://www.youtube.com/channel/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx?foo=bar#1')
# => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx?foo=bar#1"

'http://www.youtube.com/channel/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx?foo=bar#1'.split('/').last
# => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx?foo=bar#1"
```

so simply treating it as a filename won't work and to peel it apart you might as well use a URL parser. Using Ruby's built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) class will help:

```
require 'uri'
path = URI.parse('http://www.youtube.com/channel/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx?foo=bar#1').path # => "/channel/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
File.basename(path) # => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking to do is save the last portion of the URL you can loop over over the string, saving the index of each '/' into an array. Then create a new substring that runs from that index until the end of the string. I think it would look something like this...

```
indices = (0..url_string.length).find_all { |i| url_string[i] == "/" }
desired_substring = url_string[indices[-1],url_string.length-1]
```